# MemoryCache - AbsoluteExpiration - item does not expire *after update*

Tags: c#, memorycache

Below is the code to cache invalid login attempts made by user. Items are being added to cache with 'Absolute Expiration' cache policy.

If I just add one item - it expires as expected in 2 minutes. But if I update that cached item(without explicitly specifying cache policy) - the item remains much longer than 2 minutes. Here is the code snippet:

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> InvalidLoginTimestamp { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
}    

private void AddInvalidLoginToCache(string cacheKey)
{
    if (invalidLoginCache.Contains(cacheKey))
    {
        //Add invalid login to cache
        UserLogin invalidLogin = (UserLogin)invalidLoginCache[cacheKey];
        invalidLogin.InvalidLoginTimestamp.Add(DateTime.Now);
        invalidLoginCache[cacheKey] = invalidLogin;

        //Lock user account if invalid logins reach threshold
        if (invalidLogin.InvalidLoginTimestamp.Count == 3)
        {
            invalidLogin.IsLocked = true;
            invalidLoginCache.Set(cacheKey, invalidLogin, GetCachePolicyForLockOut());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        invalidLoginCache.Add(cacheKey,
                                new UserLogin { Username = cacheKey, InvalidLoginTimestamp = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now } },
                                GetCachePolicyForInvalidLogin());
    }
}

private CacheItemPolicy GetCachePolicyForInvalidLogin()
{
    int keepInvalidLoginFor = 2; //minutes
    CacheItemPolicy cachePolicyForInvalidLogin = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(keepInvalidLoginFor) };
    return cachePolicyForInvalidLogin;
}
```

It seems the issue is to do with when I am updating the cache item under //Add invalid login to cache

Any ideas on what I am missing here and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You say "the item remains longer than expected". What did you expect, and what did you see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ILSpy reveals that:

```
invalidLoginCache[cacheKey] = invalidLogin;
```

is equivalent to:

```
invalidLoginCache.Set(
    cacheKey, invalidLogin, 
    ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration, null);
```

Does this explain what you're seeing?

Why don't you call Set, passing an explicit policy?

Comment: Just a fyi, Microsoft updated http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ so you can look at the .NET source without needing to use ILSpy anymore (you can even [direct link to functions in it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCache.cs.html#e8dad1aff6cc74cb))

Comment: Yes, it does help me in understanding the reason of taking longer. I was updating as "invalidLoginCache[cacheKey] = invalidLogin;"  because I wanted the invalidLogin cache item to expire on the basis of first invalid login attempt. If I use Set method, it will be expired on the basis of 3rd invalid login attempt - 3 being maximum invalid logins allowed by a user. Do you see any workaround if I want to expire the cache on the basis of first invalid attempt?

Comment: @user1552869 - in that case I don't see why you have the line "invalidLoginCache[cacheKey] = invalidLogin;" at all.  You add a timestamp to your already-cached invalidLogin object - isn't that enough?

Comment: Oh Genius, indeed it's enough. Didn't realize that updating object is enough. Thank you!